# Jupyter matplotlib inline mode with out-of-scope plt annotations

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have some plotting functions that are called in a jupyter notebook. The plotting functions include the calls

```
plt.figure()
```

and

```
plt.show()
```

However, the notebooks add annotations to the plot after the fact. The annotations work properly with

```
%matplotlib nbagg
```

but not

```
%matplotlib inline
```

which creates a new figure instead of annotating the old one (edit: this is the same behaviour as running a script in terminal). It seems that there's a scoping issue that nbagg circumvents and that inline does not. See below for a minimal reproducible example.

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotter():
    plt.figure()
    x = np.arange(-3,3,0.1)
    y = np.exp(-x*x)
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.show()

plotter()
plt.text(0, 0.5, 'gaus', horizontalalignment='center')
plt.show()
```

Question: is there a way I can get this to work in inline mode, e.g., by getting the most recently shown figure? I'd rather not edit the back-end plotting functions, which are not my own.

Comment: Try putting `%matplotlib inline` just above the function definition.

Comment: @a_ran That doesn't change the inline behaviour of creating two figures. Plus, I'm looking for a solution that does not involve editing the function definition or the file that contains it.